# angular bacon js $scope.digestObservables(observables)

Tags: angularjs, bacon.js

I am using angular bacon in my project. I am using $scope.digestObservables(observables) where observables is the key names of multiple observables. I need to know when all the observables are loaded.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  I'd like to follow/help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this function myself, but have you tried this:

```
Bacon.combineTemplate(observables)
    .onValue(function()){
        $scope.digestObservables(observables);
    });
```